# Issues Fetching record from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table in database for example :

```sql
INSERT INTO `myintrest` (`id`, `intrest`, `memberId`) VALUES
(32, 'Exercise', 9),
(33, 'Adventure', 5),
(34, 'Exercise', 5),
(35, 'Art', 5),
(38, 'Adventure', 6),
(46, 'Adventure', 9),
(47, 'Astro-science', 9),
(48, 'Crafts', 9),
(49, 'Fashion & Designing ', 9),
(52, 'Art', 6),
(53, 'Art', 9);
```

current user login id is "5". If we fetch intrest from myintrest table according to this userid we get result :

```sql
(33, 'Adventure', 5),
(34, 'Exercise', 5),
(35, 'Art', 5),
```

But My queries is how to fetch that user which have same intrest in this table.
and in this condition other user have same intrest like Adventure ,Exercise and Art.

If this three intrest have another user then he will be fetch. Hope you under stand my query.

according to this table I want member_id=9 because it have same intrest.

Please help me to fetch this record.

Comment: Must a user share ALL the same interests, or at least one?  For example, would user 6 qualify, since he also has Adventure?

Comment: @Balraj: Do you want at least one common interest or every interest of other user should be required users interest?

Answer (score 3):

Try like this using sub-query,

```
SELECT `memberId` FROM `myintrest` where `intrest` in (SELECT
 `intrest` FROM `myintrest`  where `memberId` = $loginUserId );
```

Comment: It will give every member having at least one common interest

Comment: Yes I was use it but it's return all member id because if any one match with any login user intrest then it's show. I need only those record which have same intrest, means other person have same intrest in this table.

any solution I get only 9 member_id because 9 member id have those intrest. he member have also other intrest but include login person intrest so this is also working for this user. Hope you understand my problem. I have ask to my other friends but no one have any solution for this. please help me to solve this.

Thanks
Balraj

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `intrest` FROM `myintrest`  where `memberId` = $loginUserId;
```

This will give all interests of user $loginUserId.

```
//$arr_interests_loginUserId = array of all interests of user $loginUserId

Method 1:

    $condition='';
    foreach( $i=0; $i< count($arr_interests_loginUserId);$i++){
     $condtion.= $arr_interests_loginUserId[$i].' AND ';
    }

    $condtion.= $arr_interests_loginUserId[count($arr_interests_loginUserId)];

    "SELECT `memberId` FROM `myintrest` where $condtion ";

Method 2:

"SELECT `memberId` FROM `myintrest` where ".implode(' AND ', $arr_interests_loginUserId);
```

This will give you users having every interest of user $loginUserId.

If you require at least one common interest, then directly use this sql (suggested by Rikesh Shah):

```
SELECT `memberId` FROM `myintrest` where `intrest` in (SELECT
 `intrest` FROM `myintrest`  where `memberId` = $loginUserId );
```

Comment: to make the WHERE statement, use $condtion = implode(' AND ', $arr_interests_loginUserId); More verbose

Comment: Yes we can do by this way also...@DirkMcQuickly.